# Callback in Custom React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following hooks:

```js
function useLogin(state, url, loginMessage, callback) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const logged_in = state.user.authenticated;
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!logged_in) {history.push(url); loginMessage();}
    else callback();
  }, [logged_in])
  return logged_in;
}

function useGroupAuth(state, url, loginMessage) {
  const history = useHistory();
  let has_group_auth = false;
  state.user.available_teams.forEach(function(currentValue) {
    if (currentValue.toString().toLowerCase() === teamname.toString().toLowerCase()) {
      has_group_auth = true;
    }
  })
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!has_group_auth) {
      if (state.user.available_teams.length != 0) {
        history.push(url); loginMessage();
      }
      else
        history.push("/"); loginMessage();
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, [has_group_auth])
  return has_group_auth;
}
```

and they're used as

```js
let loggedin = useLogin(state, "/accounts/login", teamhome2_message);
let properauth = useGroupAuth(state, ("/team/" + state.user.available_teams[0]), teamhome3_message);
useEffect(() => {
  if (loggedin)
    if (properauth)
      checkteamexists(teamname);
}, []);
```

The problem is that, even though the code compiles, it's not behaving as I wanted it to. I only want `if (properauth)` to execute if `loggedin` is true.

My previous implementation worked because I was simply using callback without any custom hooks, as such:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    checklogin(function() {
      checkauth(function() {
        checkteamexists(teamname);
      })
    })
  }, []);
```

How can I ensure that `properauth` won't execute unless `loggedin` is true, as described in the initial, hook-less useEffect hook?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a way for `if (properauth)` to run if `loggedIn` is false. Unless the issue is that `loggedIn` (i.e. `state.user.authenticated`) is initially false when the `useEffect` hook runs and then the hook never runs again since there are no dependencies?

Comment: What is the initial value of `state.user.authenticated`? Unless it `true`, there's no way for `if (properauth)` to execute.

Comment: `state.user.authenticated` is false when I was running the code. For some reasons, this is the result that I get -- both hooks were executed.

Comment: And yes, when the useEffect hook runs, `state.user.authenticated` is false and the hook will never run again (until I call the body function again).

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you can't update the useGroupAuth value. because it's returning only one value send one more variable(callback) to update/check whenever you need it. something like **useState**

Hook

```
function useGroupAuth(state, url, loginMessage) {
  const history = useHistory();
  const [has_group_auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  const validate = () => {
    setAuth(
      state.user.available_teams.some(
        (currentValue) =>
          currentValue.toString().toLowerCase() ===
          teamname.toString().toLowerCase()
      )
    );
  };


  useEffect(validate, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!has_group_auth) {
      if (state.user.available_teams.length != 0) {
        history.push(url);
        loginMessage();
      } else history.push("/");
      loginMessage();
    } else {
      callback();
    }
  }, [has_group_auth]);

  return [has_group_auth, validate];
}
```

Use

```
let [properauth, reValidate] = useGroupAuth(state, ("/team/" + state.user.available_teams[0]), teamhome3_message);


useEffect(() => {
  if (loggedin){
    // Do something
    reValidate();
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Do I have to change anything to the `useLogin` hook?

Comment: If you want to update value you can. You can do same wherever you need.

Comment: What is the `// do something` supposed to be?

Comment: It's just a placeholder, not the exact code. You can write your extra checks if you want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are missing dependencies in your `useEffect` hook. Both `loggedin` and `properauth` (`teamname` as well, really) are referenced in the effect callback, so they should be included in the effect's dependencies.

```
const loggedin = useLogin(state, "/accounts/login", teamhome2_message);
const properauth = useGroupAuth(state, ("/team/" + state.user.available_teams[0]), teamhome3_message);

useEffect(() => {
  if (loggedin && properauth && teamname) {
    checkteamexists(teamname);
  }
}, [loggedin, properauth, teamname]);
```

Comment: Missing dependencies is a separate issue. OP's claiming that `if (properauth)` executes even when `loggedin` is false which is not possible.

Comment: Yet, `loggedin` and `properauth` were executed at the same time. I don't like it -- I want `properauth` to only execute if `loggedin` returns true.

Comment: @crimsonpython24 with this condition: `loggedin && properauth`, `properauth` will only be evaluated if `loggedin` is true. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: `properauth` itself will trigger side effects, no?

Comment: @crimsonpython24 JS uses short-circuiting logic, `properauth` of `loggedin && properauth && teamname` would only be evaluated ***if*** `loggedin` was truthy, and the same for `teamname` with the conditions before it.

Comment: @crimsonpython24 I'm not sure I follow your question, or if you don't quite understand how the component lifecycle works. `properauth` is computed each render cycle, so if it's in a hook's dependency array the hook's callback will be invoked, but this is why you check conditionals within the callback.

Comment: I tested it again -- for some reasons, `properauth` still showed the notification even if `loggedin` is false. I'll try logging it again and confirm.

Comment: @crimsonpython24 That's just not possible, at all. Are you console logging `loggedin` somewhere right after enqueueing a state update for it, where it's just logging the current state, not the updated state?

Comment: I am logging it between the two `let` statements and the `useEffect` hook. It's compiling now and Ill update asap.

Comment: Somehow `console.log(loggedin, properauth)` returns two `false`. I am positive that I didn't log anything incorrectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233872/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-crimsonpython24).